# Hosting Pre-Built HTML Filesystem on Spring MVC website

Tags: html, spring

I am developing a Spring MVC application and I've been given a request to host a filesystem of html files that has already been constructed. You can open one of the files with chrome and it is fully structured - it uses relative paths for links.

How can I host this file system within my application? Is it possible to use static resources to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You just need to configure a resource resolver:

```
 <mvc:resources location="file:c:/where/ever/" mapping="/yourPreBuildUrlPrefix/**"/>
```